# A question on TikZ's nonzero rule

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help on how TikZ's [`nonzero rule`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/nonzero:rule) works.  It says that it counts the number of crossings of a ray starting from some points.  The [official example in `fill` with a triangle and a circle](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/fill) has lost me, because the intersection between the triangle and the circle isn't filled.

To understand this, I adapted that example and added a second example of two circles.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[fill=yellow]
    % Clockwise isoceles right-angled triangle
    (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0) --cycle
    % Small circle centered on the leftmost vertex
    (0,0) circle (.5);

  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (.3,.3);
  \draw[->] (1,1) -- (1.5,.5);
  \draw[->] (2,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw[->] (120:.5) arc (120:90:.5);
  \draw[->] (300:.5) arc (300:270:.5);

  \draw[->] (.2,.1) -- +(0,1) node[above] {crossings: $1+1 = 2$};

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
    \filldraw[fill=yellow]
      % Two circles
      (0,0) circle (.5)
      (.5,0) circle (.5);

      \draw[->] (120:.5) arc (120:90:.5);
      \draw[->] (300:.5) arc (300:270:.5);
      \draw[->] (120:.5)+(.5,0) arc (120:90:.5);
      \draw[->] (300:.5)+(.5,0) arc (300:270:.5);
      
    \draw[->] (.2,.1) -- +(0,1) node[above] {crossings: $1+1 = 2$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've difficulty understanding the following:

1. In the 1st example, the intersection part is NOT filled.
2. In the 2nd example, the intersection part is filled.

because the number of crossings are the same.  Can you please explain why that happens?

Comment: the first has one clockwise and one anticlockwise path so 1-1=0

Comment: All the arrows on the circles are pointing the wrong way.

Comment: thx for comments. :)  you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected the drawing direction of the circles by reversing it with `[x radius=-\r, y radius=\r]`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=yellow]
(0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0) --cycle
(0,0) circle[x radius=-0.5, y radius=0.5];
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (.3,.3);
\draw[->] (1,1) -- (1.5,.5);
\draw[->] (2,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->] (120:.5) arc (120:90:.5);
\draw[->] (300:.5) arc (300:270:.5);
\draw[->] (.2,.1) -- +(0,1) node[above] {crossings: $1+1 = 2$};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\filldraw[fill=yellow]
(0,0) circle[x radius=-0.5, y radius=0.5]
(.5,0) circle[x radius=-0.5, y radius=0.5];
\draw[->] (120:.5) arc (120:90:.5);
\draw[->] (300:.5) arc (300:270:.5);
\draw[->] (120:.5)+(.5,0) arc (120:90:.5);
\draw[->] (300:.5)+(.5,0) arc (300:270:.5);
\draw[->] (.2,.1) -- +(0,1) node[above] {crossings: $1+1 = 2$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram with filled circles and triangels]

Comment: The short `arc (120:90:.5)` notation should not be used - see manual p. 160

Comment: [tikz manual p. 160:]
_There also exists a shorter syntax for the arc operation, namely `arc` begin directly followed by `(<start angle>:<end angle>:<radius>)`.  However, this syntax is harder to read, so the normal syntax should be preferred in general._